# Getting "The current path, X didn’t match any of these." even though utls.py are configued

Tags: python, django

I have a weird problem with django not finding my file. Should be basic, but I cannot figure that out. If my app name is `convers` and the the file `convers/urls.py` (same folder as where `settings.py` is) reads:

```
form django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('c/',include('convers_app.urls')),
    path('conversapp/',include('convers_app.urls')),
    path('',RedirectView.as_view(url='conversapp/')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

the `urls.py` in my `convers_app` folder reads

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('timer', views.timer, name='timer')
    ]
```

and in my `views.py` folder I have
def timer(request):
return render(request, 'timer.html')

I also have the `timer.html` in my `templates` folder.

What am I missing? Why won't django locate my `timer`view?

Comment: which url you are using to access `timer` view? could you please add views file too??

Comment: Moreover, why there are 2 url include for `convers_app`? 
`path('c/',include('convers_app.urls')),
 path('conversapp/',include('convers_app.urls')),`

Comment: Add a slash at the end of `path('timer/', ...)`.

Comment: @Sabil OK, that was embarrassing. I didn't add the 'c' or the 'coversapp' in my url. Thanks. As for your question, I'm lazy, so I've added both options.

Comment: Is your issue resolved or you still face that issue? Have you add views.py?

Comment: Yes, it is resolved. Thanks